# Why showing error in Context.Response.Write()

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, ajax, serialization

I'm new in ASP.Net development, and facing problem in sending data from webService to webform. I'm using JSON method,but in following line of code I'm having issue. The compiler shows this error message.

> "Error    3   Invalid token '(' in class, struct, or interface member
>   declaration

Can someone tell me what is the problem?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Services;
using System.Web.Script.Serialization;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data;
using System.Runtime.Remoting.Contexts;
using System.Runtime.Remoting;

/// <summary>
/// Summary description for GetStudent
/// </summary>
[WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
[WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
// To allow this Web Service to be called from script, using ASP.NET AJAX, uncomment the following line. 
[System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
public class GetStudent : System.Web.Services.WebService {

    [WebMethod]
    public GetStudent () {

        //Uncomment the following line if using designed components 
        //InitializeComponent(); 
    }

    [WebMethod]
    public void GetStudent () {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=(LocalDB)\\v11.0;AttachDbFilename='C:\\Users\\Abdul Basit Mehmood\\Documents\\Visual Studio 2012\\WebSites\\WebSite1\\App_Data\\Database.mdf';Integrated Security= True");
        List<StudentsList> stu = new List<StudentsList>();
        con.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand();
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        cmd.CommandText = "Select * From Student";
        SqlDataReader DR = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        while (DR.Read())
        {
            StudentsList student = new StudentsList();
            student.Id = Convert.ToInt32(DR["Id"]);
            student.name = DR["name"].ToString();
            student.fname = DR["fname"].ToString();
            student.email = DR["email"].ToString();
            student.contact = DR["contact"].ToString();
            student.Pname = DR["Pname"].ToString();
            student.Cname = DR["Cname"].ToString();
            StudentsList.Add(student);

        }

        JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer(StudentsList());
        Context.Response.Write(js.Serializ(StudentsList));
    }


}
```

Comment: `js.Serializ` should be `js.serialize` if it is not a typo

Comment: You should show us more code in order to get help. Here is my guess; In your class definition give a default value to StudentList (Using constructor).

Comment: I,ev edited "js.Serializ" to "js.Serialize" but did,nt make any difference

Comment: Please consider renaming your `StudentList` class to `Student`. It is very confusing since it represents single student entity.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how you need to fix your `GetStudent` method -

```
    [WebMethod]
    public void GetStudent () {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=(LocalDB)\\v11.0;AttachDbFilename='C:\\Users\\Abdul Basit Mehmood\\Documents\\Visual Studio 2012\\WebSites\\WebSite1\\App_Data\\Database.mdf';Integrated Security= True");
        List<StudentsList> stu = new List<StudentsList>();
        con.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand();
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        cmd.CommandText = "Select * From Student";
        SqlDataReader DR = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        while (DR.Read())
        {
            StudentsList student = new StudentsList();
            student.Id = Convert.ToInt32(DR["Id"]);
            student.name = DR["name"].ToString();
            student.fname = DR["fname"].ToString();
            student.email = DR["email"].ToString();
            student.contact = DR["contact"].ToString();
            student.Pname = DR["Pname"].ToString();
            student.Cname = DR["Cname"].ToString();
            stu.Add(student); //Changed line: Changed variable name to stu which is the list variable declared earlier.

        }
    JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer(); //changed line : Removed the invalid parameter to the constructor of JavaScriptSerializer class
    Context.Response.Write(js.Serializ(stu)); //changed line : Used the correct stu list variable declared at the starting of the method.
}
```

**Note**: Please follow extreme caution while naming your class. Your `StudentList` entity isn't a list but an individual student entity with various properties like `Id`,`name`,`fname` etc. Please consider renaming it to `Student`.

In order to validate that you aren't getting any invalid characters from your database first try running if below code works fine or not?

```
class Program
{
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<StudentsList> stu = new List<StudentsList>();

            StudentsList student = new StudentsList();
            student.name = "Abdul Basit Mehmood";
            student.fname = "Abdul";
            stu.Add(student); 
            JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer(); 
            var serializedValue = js.Serialize(stu); 
         }
}

class StudentsList
{
    public string name;
    public string fname;
}
```

`serializedValue` variable should show you a valid JSON string in quick watch window as shown below:

[image]

Comment: Thnnks for help. But it is not working. I have changed the code as you said, but error is still there. Contaxt.Response.Write"("js.Serialize"("stu")");. The error is shown at double qouted brackets in the line mentioned above.

Comment: secondly, i have declared and using Student List as a list in Default.aspx.cs."List<StudentsList> allStudent= new List<StudentsList>();
            using (MyDatabaseEntity de = new MyDatabaseEntity)
            {
                allStudent=de.TopStudent.ToList();
            }

            return allStudent;"

Comment: What error are you getting now in `Context.Response.Write(js.Serializ(stu));` code?

Comment: "Invalid token '(' in class, struct, or interface member declaration"
for all mentioned brackets.

Comment: We need to narrow down if data coming from your DB is good or not. I've edited my post to add a new code snippet. Check it if it works fine then you need to debug your DB reader part which might be pushing invalid characters into the `StudentList` object properties you are populating inside while loop.